# Converting audio samples with bit depth 8 into audio samples with bit depth 16

Tags: c++, c, audio, audio-streaming

How can I convert 8-bit audio samples into 16-bit audio samples?

Current audio configurations are:-

codec: PCM U8,Channels: Mono, Sample rate: 8000 Hz, Bits per sample: 8

how can I convert audio with above configuration into audio with below configurations without using audio conversion tools:-

codec: PCM S16LE, Channels: Mono, Sample rate: 8000 Hz, Bits per sample: 16

Can anyone explain with the help of c code?

Comment: You can copy the 8-bit samples to the new 16-bit format. However, while your audio will technically be encoded in 16-bit, it will still be the same data, ie. it will not sound like it was encoded with a 16-bit resolution.

Comment: uint16_t aud_dat = (uint16_t)(buf[i] << 8) is correct or not? Here buf is unsigned character array.

Comment: Sorry, underspecified. "U8" audio is not a standard format. You have to know how these values should be interpreted. There are at least two common 8 bit encodings, G.711 A-law and G.711 mu-Law. There are used in phone calls; both are also encodings used with 8kHz sample rate.

Comment: While streaming the audio data, codec is showing as PCM U8 and bitspersample showing as 8 under media information. For applying above mentioned encoding to an audio data, bit depth must be 16 or more.

Comment: @Ansu it does not seem correct, because your format is named "S16" with S for signed. So the bounds should be those of a signed 16bit int instead: shift by 7 bits, add minimum (negative) value of signed 16 bit int

Comment: @ Florian Castellane Thanks for your suggestions. It works fine now.